# ExtJS 6 adding workspace.json to gitignore

Tags: git, extjs

I have a quick ExtJS 6 question that im hoping someone can help me with.

I am working in a multi dev team using git for source control.

I have setup a brand new Ext project via the following steps;

```
sencha -sdk /home/user/project/extjs-6.5.3.57 generate app Application /home/user/project/app
```

which builds the app, I then run `sencha app watch` and do some initial changes.

From there i `git init` a initial commit.

All seems to go well, it creates an entry in my workspace.json file like so;

```
"frameworks": {
    "ext": {
        "path":"ext",
        "version":"6.5.3.57"
    }

},
```

The problem occurs when another member of the team want to start developing.

They clone the repo, setup their sencha cmd and then run;

```
sencha app upgrade /home/user/project/extjs-6.5.3.57
```

This creates the /build and /ext directories which are in the .gitignore file.

Straight after this, if they were to run `git status` is returns saying that the workspace.json has been updated.

The change just seems to be checking that frameworks block and adding a few spaces. and this is the rendered block;

```
"frameworks": {
    "ext": {
        "path":"ext",
        "version":"6.5.3.57"
    }


},
```

I was wondering if anyone else has run into this and how they overcame it? .. Should i be adding workspace.json to the .gitignore file so its generated fresh on each dev's machine? or am i doing something wrong initially?

Currently my `.gitignore` looks like so;

```
/build
/ext
bootstrap.*
classic.json*
modern.json*
.sencha
.idea
```

I am running the sencha app upgrade from the root directory of the project, so my working directory looks like so

```
/.git
.gitignore
Readme.md
/app
app.js
app.json
build.xml
/classic
/ext
index.html
/modern
/resources
workspace.json
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are the generated folders in the root folder? Probably it helps if you share the specific contents of .gitignore and the relative paths of the generated folders.

Comment: @ChristosBatzilis I have updated my question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, a typical [ExtJS gitignore file](https://www.gitignore.io/api/extjs) does not include `workspace.json`.
So you should *not* ignore it.

Second, you could ask the developers to activate in their git config a `clean` `content filter driver` which would [remove empty lines](https://www.google.com/search?q=bash%20remove%20empty%20lines&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab).

```
git config filter.workspacejson.clean sed '/^$/d'
```

That filter '`workspacejson`' is declared in the Git repository as a [`.gitattributes` directive](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_code_filter_code).

```
workspace.json  filter=workspacejson
```

It will apply automatically on `git diff` or `git commit` for any `workspace.json` file, as specified in the `.gitattributes` file.

[image: http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/book/08-customizing-git/images/clean.png]

<sup>(Source: [Pro Git book: Customizing Git - Git Attributes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes))</sup>

That way, any `git diff` or `git commit` will consider your `workspace.json` unchanged.

Comment: This seems to be the way to go ... Thank you for your help